# understanding phpexcel RATE function

Tags: php

The Formula call for variables.  I've look all over and can't find what these variables are and what values they're supposed to represent.

```
RATE($nper, $pmt, $pv, $fv = 0.0, $type = 0, $guess = 0.1)
```

Is anyone familiar with this function?  Do you know what values the variables are meant to represent?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `phpexcel`, but surely there are docs

Comment: @MarcB : Please see the question title.  Visit this website if you're unfamiliar with the code.  http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/  Or, if you're unfamiliar with the difference between server scripting and magic, this link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_(paranormal)

Comment: tplummer: phpexcel is simply a php library to manipulate excel files. if you're embedding a spreadsheet function, it doesn't matter WHAT library you're doing it with - the library cannot embed a function that excel itself doesn't support.

Comment: @MarcB: Excel supports RATE().  I'm using it.  Just so we're on the same page... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3198939/recreate-excel-rate-function-using-newtons-method

Comment: and that's what I'm saying as well... you should have gone straight to the Excel documentation instead of asking about phpexcel here.

Comment: I don't think you're really saying much of anything, to be honest with you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Excel help file:

> ```
> RATE(nper,pmt,pv,fv,type,guess)
> ```
>
> For a complete description of the arguments nper, pmt, pv, fv, and
>   type, see PV.
>
> - Nper - is the total number of payment periods in an annuity.
> - Pmt - is the payment made each period and cannot change over the life of the annuity. Typically, pmt includes principal and interest
>     but no other fees or taxes. If pmt is omitted, you must include the fv
>     argument.
> - Pv - is the present value — the total amount that a series of future payments is worth now.
> - Fv - is the future value, or a cash balance you want to attain after the last payment is made. If fv is omitted, it is assumed to be 0 (the
>     future value of a loan, for example, is 0).
> - Type - is the number 0 or 1 and indicates when payments are due.
>
>   Set type equal to the following if payments are due:
>
>   - 0 or omitted - At the end of the period
>   - 1 - At the beginning of the period
> - Guess - is your guess for what the rate will be.
>
>   If you omit guess, it is assumed to be 10 percent.
>     If RATE does not converge, try different values for guess. RATE usually converges if guess is between 0 and 1.
>
> ### Remark
>
> Make sure that you are consistent about the units you use for
>   specifying guess and nper. If you make monthly payments on a four-year
>   loan at 12 percent annual interest, use 12%/12 for guess and 4*12 for
>   nper. If you make annual payments on the same loan, use 12% for guess
>   and 4 for nper

Comment: Should've figured it used the same variables as the Excel function since it's meant to be a clone. Thanks!

Comment: Please don't just blindly copy/paste from a manual, make sure your data is presentable. I've put exactly 2 minutes in editing this post, you should do it yourself next time.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: while yours certainly looks nicer, I felt that the text was readable enough, especially since most people wanting to use Excel functions have the Excel manual available to them.  If you have a look at my posting history you'll see that I spend quite a bit of time editing for presentation.  I very rarely "blindly" paste in anything. Thanks for prettifying my post, but please don't assume I posted without thought.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if you need to implement this function, but in any case, I looked at how this algorithm was built and even though I was not able to access the excel source code (or the google worksheet) I found that this is not a simple calculation. About this math, more can be read here:

https://brownmath.com/bsci/loan.htm#Eq8

The function, in PHP, may be something like this:

```
function rate($nprest, $vlrparc, $vp, $guess = 0.25) {
    $maxit = 100;
    $precision = 14;
    $guess = round($guess,$precision);
    for ($i=0 ; $i<$maxit ; $i++) {
        $divdnd = $vlrparc - ( $vlrparc * (pow(1 + $guess , -$nprest)) ) - ($vp * $guess);
        $divisor = $nprest * $vlrparc * pow(1 + $guess , (-$nprest - 1)) - $vp;
        $newguess = $guess - ( $divdnd / $divisor );
        $newguess = round($newguess, $precision);
        if ($newguess == $guess) {
            return $newguess;
        } else {
            $guess = $newguess;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```